# PHP file with two CSS files

Tags: php, css

---

### editing here:

Before continue reading, I wanna be clear that I'm calling two CSS files and just one of them is recognized on my resulting HTML page. Common problems are:

1) wrong name, like a typo. (I checked, it's not the case).

2) Wrong directory (I checked, it's not the case too).

3) Tow files with the same name (Checked...)

I already exchanged the position between the `link` tags and still not working.

Remembering: One CSS file works fine, and the other CSS file which is in the same directory doesn't.

---

### The original question bellow:

I know this is an elementary question, but I really don't understand what is happening with my code.
First, I have a index.php page, which request a password to the user. If everything goes fine here (if statements and validations) I include the real index content through `include INCS_PATH.'index.inc';`, where `INCS_PATH` is a constant defined to a directory.

Including this index.inc, I have:

```
<head>
    <title>MY TITLE HERE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>style.css" />
</head>
```

As we can see, I called two CSS files and the client side got the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

My `style.css` is:

```
#content-box {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.row, .column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.column + .column {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.column-1 {
    width: 6.5%;
}

.column-2 {
    width: 15.0%;
}

.column-3 {
    width: 23.5%;
}

.column-4 {
    width: 32.0%;
}

.column-5 {
    width: 40.5%;
}

.column-6 {
    width: 49.0%;
}

.column-7 {
    width: 57.5%;
}

.column-8 {
    width: 66.0%;
}

.column-9 {
    width: 74.5%;
}

.column-10 {
    width: 83.0%;
}

.column-11 {
    width: 91.5%;
}

.column-12 {
    width: 100.0%;
}

.to-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.to-left {
    text-align: left;
}

.to-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

which has a responsive hole in my system. The `index.css` is the CSS file to especific style to the `index.html` as result of the PHP file:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 21cm;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.values {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

My question:

1) Doesn't matter what I code in my `index.css` file, it seems isn't recognized by HTML resulting file (main question, if answered, I consider my whole question solved)

2) My last three classes in `style.css` file `.to-left`, `.to-center` and `.to-right` aren't recognized too...

Since now, thank you so much!

---- editing: more information -----

Here are my constants `_PATH`:

```
define('SIST_URL','http://someurl.here');
define('CONFIG_PATH','config/');
define('CSS_PATH','css/');
define('HIDESEEK_PATH','HideSeek/');
define('INCS_PATH','includes/');
define('JQUERY_PATH','jQuery/');
define('JS_PATH','js/');
define('PHP_PATH','php/');
define('IMG_PATH','imagens/');
```

and here the code source untill my last development:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>CONTACTO IMÓVEIS | GERADOR DE RELATÓRIOS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content-box">
        <!-- INCLUINDO CABEÇALHO -->
        <header class="row">
    <span class="column column-2 to-right">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="column column-2 to-right">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="column column-2 to-right">
        <img src="imagens/logo.jpg" title="Contacto Imóveis" alt="Logotipo Contacto" />
    </span>
    <span class="column column-2">
        <h1>CONTACTO<br/>IMÓVEIS</h1>
    </span>
    <span class="column column-2 to-right">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="column column-2 to-right">&nbsp;</span>
</header>       <!-- INCLUINDO CORPO -->
        <section class="row">
            <h2 class="column column-12 to-center">RECIBO DE ENTRADA</h2>
            <form method="post" action="/contacto/index.php">
                <!--                    -->
                <!-- INSERÇÃO DE TEXTO  -->
                <!--                    -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column column-6 to-left">
                        <p>LOCADOR<br/>
                            <input type="text" name="locador" placeholder="Nome completo do locador" />                     </p>
                        <p>LOCATÁRIO<br/>
                            <input type="text" name="locatario" placeholder="Nome completo do locatário" />                         
                        </p>
                        <p>ENDEREÇO<br/>
                            <input type="text" name="endereco" placeholder="Nome da rua, nº, complemento, bairro, cidade - estado" />                       </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column column-6 to-right">
                        <p>COMISSÃO
                            <select name="comissao">\n\t<option value="10%" selected>10%</option>\n\t<option value="5%">5%</option>\n</select>                      </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--                     -->
                <!-- INSERÇÃO DE VALORES -->
                <!--                     -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column column-4 to-left">
                        <ul class="values">
                            <li>Aluguel</li>
                            <li>Multa</li>
                            <li>IPTU</li>
                            <li>Água</li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="button" value="Inserir campos" id="more-fields" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="column column-4 to-center">
                        <input type="date" name="data" />                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="column column-4 to-right">
                        <ul class="values">
                            <li>R$<input type="text" name="aluguel" placeholder="0,00" /></li>
                            <li>R$<input type="text" name="multa" placeholder="0,00" /></li>
                            <li>R$<input type="text" name="iptu" placeholder="0,00" /></li>
                            <li>R$<input type="text" name="agua" placeholder="0,00" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="go" />
            </form>
        </section>
        <!-- INCLUINDO RODAPÉ -->
        <footer class="row">
    <span class="column column-4">
        &nbsp;
    </span>
    <span class="column column-4">
        <p>São Gonçalo, _____ / _____ / _____</p>
        <p>Assinatura: _________________________________</p>
    </span>
    <span class="column column-4">
        &nbsp;
    </span>
    <hr class="column column-12" />
    <address class="column column-12">
        <p>(21) 2712-0651   |   Rua Coronel Moreira César, 151 - Centro - São Gonçalo - RJ  |   www.contactoimoveis.com.br</p>
    </address>
</footer>   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your CSS_PATH?

Comment: Also check through `view source` on browser, that your `css` files are actually included in html code are not.

Comment: How about `ctrl + f5` ?

Comment: Possibly there is no directory named "css" relative to the index.php page. You should see that causing 404 errors in the console window of your favorite browser's developer tools.

Comment: You're using `.inc` as an extension and using PHP directives. Did you instruct your server to treat those as PHP? No? Well there's the problem then. PHP doesn't know "how" to treat those and won't parse them by default. *"to especific style to the index.html"* - Again, did you instruct your system to treat `.html` files as PHP? and how are you accessing this, as `http://localhost.file.xxx` or `c:///file.xxx`?

Comment: @TommiHalonen, I've already done it.

Comment: @StefanSeiz, no 404 error. There are two CSS files in css/ directory. Since one of them works I think the files are (at least one of them) be found.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm in localhost/contacto (my system name is contacto). I think the `.inc` format is not the problem since it's recognized and the `style.css` applies to all `.inc`s which I include. I'm working in PHP I'm run the code from localhost WAMP server, because c://... just could show me the source code.

Comment: @luweiqi, `CSS_PATH` is `css/` relative to index.php path. I edited my question to include all defined constants about URLs.

Comment: @Anant, I edited my question to include my source code from browser (google chrome). As we can see, the `<link>` are there. I think this is not the problem too because one of them is recognized and works fine, even the other one seems don't be there.

Comment: Does you index.php page include any inline styles that could be overwriting the styles in the stylesheets? Have you posted the full contents of your stylesheets as specifity could be a factor here. When viewing your source code, if you follow the links to your stylesheets do they display correctly in a browser on their own? e.g http://yousite.com/css/style.css

Comment: @TommyBs, please, make an answer with your comment and I set it as a solved. I did it to `style.css` and it was ok, but `index.css` just showed the content `body { }`. Maybe I was editing another index.css file of other project in my sublime window. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does you index.php page include any inline styles that could be overwriting the styles in the stylesheets? Have you posted the full contents of your stylesheets as specifity could be a factor here. When viewing your source code, if you follow the links to your stylesheets do they display correctly in a browser on their own? e.g yousite.com/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to prepend your CSS path with a forward slash as it looks like the base path has not been set.

```
define('CSS_PATH','/css/');
```

That could fix your issue.

A hot tip: 
Use your browser to view the source and see if you can click the urls for the CSS files. 
If you get a 404 not found error, you know that the browser can't find the stylesheets..

Comment: I did it to `style.css` and it was ok, but `index.css` just showed the content `body { }`. Maybe I was editing another index.css file of other project in my sublime window. Thank you so much